# Table with fixed left column. Row height issue due to position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a **table with the first left column fixed**. I used a CSS-only solution that's working fine except a peculiar issue due to the use of '*position: absolute;*'.

You may see it at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k12crdmc/1/).

The rows of the first column don't match the rows of the second column. I set **border="1"** to highlight the problem. I need that the rows' height match because I would like to draw a shadow on the vertical right border of the first column so that when the user scrolls the table horizontally it seems that the columns slide under the first one (a well known effect, though).

**As you see the shadow is 'fragmented' and this is due to '*position: absolute;*'** but the fixed column won't work without absolute positioning.

After hours of attempts to find a pure CSS solution I guess some Javascript/Jquery should solve the problem by getting the height of the row of the second column and setting it on the row of the first column.

Kind of this (not working):

```
$('tr th').each(function(i) {
    var RowTwo = $('tr td:nth-child(2)').get(i);
    $(this).height($(RowTwo).height());
);
```

I'm not good in Javascript/Jquery so I'm stuck here.

Please notice the following:

- the HTML can be changed only slightly becase it is the result of a
  XSL/XML transformation
- the table may be only one (not two tables side by side)
- THEAD uses THs
- TBODY uses THs and TDs
- the JSFiddle generates a table with only 2 columns (1 + 1), but normally the table could display a greater number of columns (1 + n)

Comment: What is the reason for the `position: absolute`? Because yes it is that causing the problem.

Comment: `position: absolute` is needed to keep the first column at a fixed position. If you remove it the column will scroll as all the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work now, just getting the second child of `tr` height and setting the first child with that height.

**Note:** *You need to sort your CSS out as they look like there aren't the same height but they are. Because of the borders etc.*

**jQuery**

```
$('tr').each(function(i) {
    var rowTwo = $(this).children().eq(1).height();
    $(this).children().eq(0).height(rowTwo);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/k12crdmc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

please try using this code:

```
$('th.keys').each(function(){
        var myHeight = $(this).height();
        var sib = $(this).siblings().eq(0);
        var sibHeight = sib.height();

        var maxHeight = Math.max(myHeight,sibHeight);

        $(this).height(maxHeight);

    });
```